# Tkinter Combobox, unable to update list

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to refresh a list in a combobox, after a lot of research,  I have not been successful in finding out how this can be done. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
    Supplier_Lup.config (values=SupplierRef_List)
    Supplier_Lup = Combobox (Supplier_fr, values=SupplierRef_List, width=40, state='readonly')
    Supplier_Lup.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10, ipadx=10,  sticky='w')
    Supplier_Lup.current() # default selected option
    Supplier_Lup.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', SupplierRef_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide `SupplierRef_Input`. It should be a *function* where your will set `Supplier_Lup.config(values=SupplierRef_List)`. Here is a [minimal reproducible exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

def change_values(event):
    cb.config(values=[4,5,6])

root = tk.Tk()
cb = Combobox(master=root, values=[1, 2, 3])
cb.pack()
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', change_values)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
Supplier_Lup.config (values=SupplierRef_List)
```

to:

```
Supplier_Lup['values'] = SupplierRef_List
```